# how to map value json to object java using jackson-annotations

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a string Json :

```
{
   "title": "PowerPoint Presentation",
   "author": "Hana",
   "subject": null,
   "keywords": null,
   "created_date": "2016-03-25 15:11:17",
   "modified_date": "2016-03-28 17:27:06",
   "creator": null,
   "producer": "LibreOffice 5.0",
   "pdfversion": null,
   "file_size": 149225,
   "total_page": 24
}
```

and Object java

```
public class ContentInfo {

    @JsonProperty("title")
    private String title;

    @JsonProperty("author")
    private String author;

    @JsonProperty("subject")
    private String subject;

    @JsonProperty("keywords")
    private String keywords;

    @JsonProperty("created_date")
    private String createdDate;

    @JsonProperty("modified_date")
    private String modifiedDate;
// (application name that create original file of PDF)

    @JsonProperty("creator")
    private String creator;
// (application name that create PDF)

    @JsonProperty("producer")
    private String producer;

    @JsonProperty("pdfversion")
    private String pdfversion;

    @JsonProperty("file_size")
    private long fileSize;

    @JsonProperty("total_page")
    private long totalPage;

    public ContentInfo() {
    }

    public ContentInfo(String title, String author, String subject, String keywords, String createdDate, String modifiedDate, String creator, String producer, String pdfversion, long fileSize, long totalPage, PageViewSetting page_view_setting) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.keywords = keywords;
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
        this.modifiedDate = modifiedDate;
        this.creator = creator;
        this.producer = producer;
        this.pdfversion = pdfversion;
        this.fileSize = fileSize;
        this.totalPage = totalPage;
        this.page_view_setting = page_view_setting;
    }



    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public String getKeywords() {
        return keywords;
    }

    public String getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public String getModifiedDate() {
        return modifiedDate;
    }

    public String getCreator() {
        return creator;
    }

    public String getProducer() {
        return producer;
    }

    public String getPdfversion() {
        return pdfversion;
    }

    public long getFileSize() {
        return fileSize;
    }

    public long getTotalPage() {
        return totalPage;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public void setKeywords(String keywords) {
        this.keywords = keywords;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(String createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public void setModifiedDate(String modifiedDate) {
        this.modifiedDate = modifiedDate;
    }

    public void setCreator(String creator) {
        this.creator = creator;
    }

    public void setProducer(String producer) {
        this.producer = producer;
    }

    public void setPdfversion(String pdfversion) {
        this.pdfversion = pdfversion;
    }

    public void setFileSize(long fileSize) {
        this.fileSize = fileSize;
    }
}
```

I am using the below code to map them :

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            objectMapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
            data = objectMapper.readValue(this.jsonContentInfoData, ContentInfo.class);
```

However result ResponseBody is wrong in some field:

```
"content_info": {
"title": "PowerPoint Presentation"
"author": "Hana"
"subject": null
"keywords": null
"created_date": "2016-03-25 15:11:17"
"creator": null
"producer": "LibreOffice 5.0"
"pdfversion": null
"modified_date": "2016-03-28 17:27:06"
"file_size": 0
"total_page": 0
}
```

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint on the data= line and checked the value of `this.jsonContentInfoData` for correctness? Also, does your `ContentInfo` class have getters/setters? Your fields are private, so I'm guessing you do. I would check that those that are not set don't have properly named getter and setter.

Comment: I had debug it . this.jsonContentInfoData is correct

Comment: OK, can you show us the entire ContentInfo class then?

Comment: I have getters/setters. I just want to shorten code

Comment: Ok, but I think they are important to finding the solution. See my answer for details.

Comment: i had edit my post. could you see it again.

Answer (score 0):

Jackson serializes and deserializes based on the access modifier of your field, in conjunction with the available and properly named getter and setter method.

You can override this feature to insure all private fields are ser/deserialized using:

```
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
```

However, it's decent for testing, but isn't the optimal solution.
Instead, you should in practice use private fields and use public getters/setters to control the serialization and deserialization process.

> - A public Getter Makes a Non-Public Field Serializable and Deserializable
>
>   Unintuitively, the getter also makes the private field deserializable as well – because once it has a getter, the field is considered a property.
> - A public Setter Makes a Non-Public Field Deserializable Only

In your code, showing the getters/setters:

1. `setPdfversion` - Is incorrect: Should be `setPdfVersion`
2. `getTotalPage(long totalPage)`  - Is incorrect and is intended to be `setTotalPage(long totalPage)`

Finally, I think it will help to change the types of `totalPage` and `fileSize` from the primitive `long` to the wrapper object `Long`. Also change the getter/setters for these fields to match the `Long` types. Since both of these fields are having issues and are using primitives, it seems possible that Jackson (or your version of it) does not handle primitives.

Comment: i use private fields and use public getters/serters yet. result is the same

Comment: Please read the answer - specifically for that last 2 numbered items showing incorrectly named getter/setter

Comment: getters/and setters is auto create in netbean. it is correct standard for java

Comment: @hanit - Look at your code: You have 2 getTotalPage methods, one with no argument and one with a single argument - clearly one was intended to be a setTotalPage(). Otherwise, why would a getTotalPage(long totalPage) accept an argument?? A getter method accepting an argument is not 'correct java standards'

Comment: i had deteted a mothod with a single argument. it is no affect.

Comment: I guess that **readValue** in ObjectMapper is map parameter in string json with name of field example : file_size with file_size. no fileSize , and getter getFile_size(). @jsonProperty(file_size) is no affect.

Comment: **objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);**